# Unregister mobile menu in twenty twelve not working

Tags: theme-twenty-twelve

I use the WPTouch plugin to make my blog responsive. My theme is twenty twelve newest Version 2.2.

WPTouch works fine in mobile mode. My problem is that the twenty twelve theme activate the responsive menu, when the width of desktop is less than 600px in desktop mode.

I tried to unregister the script like here: http://wpbeaches.com/de-register-de-queue-wordpress-loaded-scripts-styles/

I also tried to delete the wp_enqueue_script completely in functions.php:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'twentytwelve-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array(  'jquery' ), '20140711', true );
```

But the mobile menu is still active, when width is lower than 600px.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Delete wp_enqueue_script navigation wont work as the navigation were being registered and stored on the database. So for this you need to deregister navigation using the code below:

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'deregister_navscript', 100 );
function deregister_navscript() {
     wp_deregister_script( 'twentytwelve-navigation' );
}
```

This code unregisters the javascript used to toggle the default responsive menu.

Add CSS to hide the default 2012 menu button and to hide the UL menu when the select menu is displayed. Insert the following code in your theme style.css:

```
/* hide the default responsive menu and menu button */
h3.menu-toggle {display: none}
.main-navigation ul.nav-menu, .main-navigation div.nav-menu > ul {display: none;}
```

Comment: I put your code in functions.php but the responsive menu is still active. Thank you for help!

Comment: The button is hide, but the menu is still active.

Comment: i believe there is some media queries in the theme's style.css that overiding the code. Could you also give your site url so that i could see the problem?

Comment: You are right! Now the menu is unregister. But now i have another problem. Under 600px now is no menu. I want the standard primary menu also for the small size resolution in desktop mode.